# flutter lint argument type rules usage

Tags: flutter, dart

How i can control witch rules i want to apply to my code.
I added lint package but argument type rules are happening to much.

I have a lot dynamic data from API calls and i tried disable theme but it didn't work.
Can i decide which rules i want to apply?
There are rules that make the code more efficient like the const rule, adding lint to active project can be headache so i think if it is worth it?

The current rules i try to disable:

```
argument_type_not_assignable: false

invalid_assignment: false
```

Article.fromMap throw The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

```
class Article {
  String id;
  String image;
  String title;
  Map contentEditor;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> teams;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> leagues;
  String content;
  String updateDate;

  Article({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.contentEditor,
    this.teams,
    this.leagues,
    this.content,
    this.updateDate,
  });

  String getDateString() {
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    return formatter.format(DateTime.parse(this.updateDate));
  }

  String getTimeString() {
    final dateTime = DateTime.parse(this.updateDate).toLocal();
    return DateFormat.Hm().format(dateTime);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'image': image,
      'title': title,
      'contentEditorId': contentEditor,
      'teams': teams,
      'leagues': leagues,
      'content': content,
      'updateDate': updateDate
    };
  }

  factory Article.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;

    return Article(
      id: map['id'],
      image: map['image'],
      title: map['title'],
      contentEditor: map['contentEditor'],
      teams: List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(map['teams']?.map((x) => x)),
      leagues: List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(map['leagues']?.map((x) => x)),
      content: map['content'],
      updateDate: map['updateDate'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Article.fromJson(Map json) => Article.fromMap(json);
}
```

I like more this approach

```
  dynamic getPoints(dynamic property) {
    if (property == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    return property.won * 3 + property.draw;
  }
```

than this:

```
 int getPoints(Map<String, int> property) {
    if (property == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    return property["won"] * 3 + property["draw"];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`argument_type_not_assignable` and `invalid_assignment` are *errors*, not lints.

You can make the Dart analyzer ignore them [by modifying your `analysis_options.yaml` file](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#ignoring-rules) to have:

```yaml
analyzer:
  errors:
    argument_type_not_assignable: ignore
    invalid_assignment: ignore
```

However, it does not make any sense to disable those rules.  Even though the *analyzer* would no longer complain about violations, violations would still be illegal and ultimately would generate compilation errors.  What would you expect `int x = 'string';` to do?

Comment: You are right but what with dynamic data from API request, i added an example ^

Comment: @nadav For that case, you could set `implicit_casts: true` (the link in my answer has an example), or (better, IMO) add explicit casts.

Comment: What implicit_casts: true is doing i didnt find out

Comment: Oops, I made a typo; I meant `implicit-casts: true`.  As the same suggests, it enables implicit downcasts.  However, I recommend using explicit casts instead since downcasts are not necessarily safe and therefore shouldn't be done accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the strict type casting by following:

```
analyzer:
  language:
    strict-casts: false
```

`strict-casts` is a language mode of `stricter type checks`.

There are 3 modes.You can find more on this at [Enabling stricter type checks](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks)